# Can't get variables from a function inside a class (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

i'm stuck with this problem, i can't read the variables **bpm** and **spo2** from the function *run_sensor* (i need these two variables in another script). If someone can help me, thanks.

```
class HeartRateMonitor(object):
LOOP_TIME = 0.10

def __init__(self, print_raw=False, print_result=False):
    self.bpm = 0
    if print_raw is True:
        print('IR, Red')
    self.print_raw = print_raw
    self.print_result = print_result



def run_sensor(self):
    sensor = MAX30102()
    ir_data = []
    red_data = []
    bpms = []
    
    # run until told to stop
    while not self._thread.stopped:
        # check if any data is available
        num_bytes = sensor.get_data_present()
        if num_bytes > 0:
            # grab all the data and stash it into arrays
            if len(ir_data) == 100:
                bpm, valid_bpm, spo2, valid_spo2 = hrcalc.calc_hr_and_spo2(ir_data, red_data)       # <-------------- here
                if valid_bpm:
                    bpms.append(bpm)
                    while len(bpms) > 4:
                        bpms.pop(0)
                    self.bpm = np.mean(bpms)
                    if (np.mean(ir_data) < 50000 and np.mean(red_data) < 50000):
                        self.bpm = 0
                        if self.print_result:
                            print("Finger not detected")
                    if self.print_result:
                      
                        print("BPM: {0}, SpO2: {1}".format(round(self.bpm), round(spo2)))
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Comment: What's the other script? If it's in another file, you should reconsider your design. Maybe `bpm` and `spo2` should be attributes of the class? You're attempting to use variables local to a function in another script, which can't be done. The answer gives the (poor) suggestion of using `global`, which may work, but is generally not a good idea.

Comment: The other script uses these two variables for a web dashboard, when i tried using global it gives me errors or the value remains 0.

Comment: i tried to assign bpm and spo2 to other variables but it keeps getting 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Global keyword for this issue. Write this -

`global bpm`

`global spo2`

under the function you need to use the variables in

Comment: well, first of all, python is case-sensitive, so `Global` should be `global`. More important - this is really poor advise, especially in OOP context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access class variables from another function. However, if you were to create an instance of the `HeartRateMonitor` class, then you can import it and get its `bpm` and `spo2`.

```
instance = HeartRateMonitor()
```

Then, in your other script:

```
from heartratemonitor.py import instance
instance.run_sensor() # I assume this is what you want to do
print(instance.bpm)
print(instance.spo2)
```

Comment: hi, i tried this and now it gives me this error:                                                                       `File "fla.py", line 9, in <module>
    instance.run_sensor()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/heartrate_monitor.py", line 32, in run_sensor
    while not self._thread.stopped:
AttributeError: 'HeartRateMonitor' object has no attribute '_thread'`

Comment: Where do you define _thread? You have to define it first.

Comment: sorry for the formatting, i couldn't post the whole code, after the last row there is :    `def start_sensor(self):
        
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_sensor)
        self._thread.stopped = False
        self._thread.start()

    def stop_sensor(self, timeout=2.0):
        self._thread.stopped = True
        self.bpm = 0
        self._thread.join(timeout)`